# How to get tab completion for LaTeX in TextMate?

Tags: development, text-editor, latex

For instance, try; `\begin{ite[tab]` but you get nothing.

How can you have tab completion for LaTeX in TextMate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextMate generally uses `esc` for completion, though certain triggers can be specified in the Bundle for tab 'completion', you can see what the triggers are by going to the `Bundles menu > Bundle Editor > Show Bundle Editor`.

Comment: I would like to get a review why they rejected TAB as an autocompletion key, but selected instead ESC. Probably, it is better to use in different environments.

Comment: It looks like the "tab triggers" could be quite a powerful feature ([TexMate manual for Tab Triggers](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles#tab_triggers)), but perhaps the Bundle authors do not make the same commitment as was originally intended.